# Blender won't correctly load the texture file (png image) in my custom startup file. Why?

Tags: texturing, startup-file

In my project I have an "Images as Planes" object. I click on the "Save Startup File" option to ensure my project and its layout loads upon starting Blender. It seems to work as expected except the displayed image is pink instead. I've read that pink means texture files are missing but it seems to remember what files to read and I have not moved the image file. Here is what my startup should look like:

[image]

This is what my startup looks like:
[image]

If I load it from my saved .blend file it works as I intended.

Unfortunately I'm not finding much helpful information through search engines about textures not loading at startup, nor do I wish to spend a couple hours changing random things to see if the result changes (as I do sometimes). I figured it's time to ask here. How do I make it so the texture loads correctly at startup?

Comment: Hello :). Weird, works just fine for me. There used to be this issue [in early 2.8](https://community.gamedev.tv/t/having-to-remind-blender-where-image-files-are-each-time-i-open-a-blend/109718/6), perhaps it's a bug. If you really need it to work, you can pack the file inside the .Blend.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you Jachym Michal for your comment, you helped me solve this.

To solve my problem I:

1. Loaded the .blend file that has what I want to load at startup.
2. File -> External Data -> Pack All Into .blend

Upon opening Blender it now displays my image correctly. :)

Comment: Images are not saved as part of the .blend file unless you pack them. When you get pink as texture instead of an image it means that blender did not find the image in the indicated path on the drive, or that the image cannot be mapped with the current coordinates.